# Ionic 2 show login page over slide menu app

Tags: authentication, modal-dialog, angular, ionic2

**Q) How to I show a login page over the top of my standard slide menu app in Ionic 2?**

My slide menu app is up and running, I just need that initial login page setup correctly.

Things I know:

- How to show a modal page with `nav.present()`.
- How to `dismiss` a modal page.

Things I **DON'T** know:

- Where to instantiate + show this page
- How to have it accessible from any current page (i.e. if the user is logged out)

**Note**: this is for Ionic 2, not 1.  I know there are many examples of this in Ionic 1, but they're not applicable thanks.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Using event listeners as follows:

1.) I have added a LoginPage to my app.ts:

```
import {Events} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
import {LoginPage} from './pages/login/login';
```

Then, I made it the rootPage:

```
class MyApp {
  rootPage: Type = LoginPage;
```

2.) Then, I register some listeners:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribeToEvents();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribeToEvents();
  }

  subscribeToEvents() {
    this._events.subscribe('login:success', () => {
      this.getNav().setRoot(TodosPage);
    });

    this._events.subscribe('logout:success', () => {
      this.getNav().setRoot(LoginPage);
    });
  }

  unsubscribeToEvents() {
    this._events.unsubscribe('login:success', null);
    this._events.unsubscribe('logout:success', null);
  }

  getNav() {
    return this.app.getComponent('nav');
  }
```

3.) Then, in my LoginPage:

```
  <button full (click)="login()">Login</button>


  login() {
    // Do some auth here first...
    this._events.publish("login:success", null);
  }
```

Comment: you need this to hide the slide menu `this.app.getComponent('your-id-tag-of-side-menu').enable(false);` in case you are not using modal.

Comment: It is not shown how you actually instantiated a modal dialog

Comment: I've changed the title to reflect that it's not a modal. You're correct.